# Exporting node project to another pc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, dependencies

I want to copy my node project from Windows to Mac (written in angular), how to do it?
I tried to copy the folder and run npm install, but it didn't work

Here is the error I am getting:

```
sh: /Users/pawelmeller/Documents/hotel/angular4/node_modules/.bi‌​n/napa:
Permission denied npm ERR!
code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
errno 126 npm ERR!
light-blue@3.8.0 install:
napa npm ERR!
Exit status 126 npm ERR!
npm ERR!
Failed at the light-blue@3.8.0 install script.
npm ERR!

This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Do you have the project in version control? You should be able to clone the repo onto the other machine. What precisely *"didn't work"*?

Comment: sh: /Users/pawelmeller/Documents/hotel/angular4/node_modules/.bin/napa: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! light-blue@3.8.0 install: `napa`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the light-blue@3.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: make sure you are having same nodejs and npm version installed on Mac machine as well, and then run npm install

Answer (score 0):

It is probably one of three reasons

1. I don't see `light-blue@3.8.0` (or any version) on the NPM registry. So it could be your internal registry causing a problem
2. If you need something installed globally, you might have to use `sudo`
3. Not all packages are 100% cross compatible - so check your dependencies

I can certainly tell you there is no problem copying projects from one to another. Node *tends* not to run with excess dependencies/libraries like other languages do. On PC you have to install a *few* other things but this is not the case on Mac.

Aside from all that, please make your answer less broad. You are not providing much context.